# Change Bootstrap 3.0 Navbar default resize to custom resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dynamic mobile website which adjusts depending on screen size.

Here is what the navbar does at the moment:

At 766px width:
[image]

768px width:
[image]

990px width:
[image]

992px width:
[image]

I basically want to cut out the 768 - 990px stage as it doesn't look very good!

I have inspected the element and found this code in the bootstrap default css this appears at the screen width of 768px:

```
media="screen"
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I have tried changing `min-width` to `992px`, but that doesnt seem to do anything.

Here is my code for the navbar:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Welsh for Adults</a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:85%;"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="taster.html">Welsh Taster Course</a></li>
                        <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="activities.html">Informal Learning Activities</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn change-lang" data-lang="cym">Cymraeg</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I have noticed it does the same thing on the bootstrap template http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar (try resizing the page slowly and the layout messes up... must be a bug within bootstrap.

Comment: It's not a bug. The breakpoint on the bootstrap.css is 768px. You can use the customizer to adjust that globally OR you can adjust the less files globally or you can create a new variable that adjusts it where you want. There's many places.

Answer (score 0):

Just override media query at one place as shown below:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/XYEu7/)

Just ensure to apply an id to the nav & use that in the CSS. I'm sure you wouldn't want the behavior to be applied to all `.container` on the page.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, try changing the size of your JS fiddle - it does the same

Comment: You sure? My fiddle manages to avoid the states between 768px & 992px.
As required, the nav layout does not flow into 2 lines. Did you try resizing only the 'Result' frame of the fiddle?

Comment: For me yours does it at `770px` wide in the jfiddle. I also have media queries to change the size of the fonts, I have a feeling it might be something to do with this!

Answer (score 0):

There are about 512 lines of navbar.css. Using less is easier! All the min-widths change from 768 to your minwidth, 992px or 1000px or whatever. You have to change the old css breaking at 768px in the appropriate places in the css.

http://jsbin.com/uwAyeGUy/2/edit

Comment: I have bootstrap all in one css file (6805) lines, so are you saying to delete the old breaking points at 768px from this file? Cheers

Comment: Only the ones associated with the navbar. You can compare between the jsbin and yours and only those media queries that are relevant change, otherwise the entire site will have issues. Make a back up

Comment: You don't delete, you change them.